# Передать значения в контроллер

Tags: javascript, php, html, yii2

Фреймворк Yii2. Как можно передать значения `<li>` - `"data-id"` и `"data-type"` при клике, в контроллер.

View

```
    $type = 'book';
    $id = 1;
    <ul>
     <li> Книги  
      <ul>
    <li data-type="' . $type .'" data-id="' . $id .'">Книга </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Controller

```
 public function actionProduct(){
                $id = ?; // значение data-id
                $type= ?; // значение data-type
        }
```

Comment: Так обдёрните само значения "Книга" в тег а и передайте в контролер.

Comment: @UKRman спасибо, получилось